# Postgres DB dump gettng Error when restore into PGADMIN 3 in linux

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I took the backup from the Postgres DB server which resides in my Windows Machine, but I am trying to restore in Postgres which resides in Linux getting Script errors like

Synatax Error at or near:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT "PLAYER_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID_fkey".
```

and its works fine with my Windows OS.

Comment: Is the Linux box running an older PostgreSQL version? What's the version on each machine?

Comment: Can you show us the full statement that generates the error?